# Solr distribution update between shards

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

How can I distribution update index between shards?
We update a collection via API solr written in Java.

*Example*

I have a collection (`coll1`) and 3 shards (`sh1`, `sh2`, `sh3`).

When i call
http://10.10.10.10:8983/solr/coll1/update?q=many_files_and_texts&wt=json&indent=true,
this **/update** will be inserted only in `sh1`, instead of all 3 shards.

Answer (score 0):

The shard in which a document gets inserted, is determined by a hash value that is computed over the document id. For more details for that see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud).

If you issue the request against the first node of your cluster hosting shard1, but the document will get inserted according to the hash value over its document id into shard2, then the first node will forward the request to the second node internally. You don't have to do anything about it. Therefore it makes sense to not insert all documents on the first node but distribute them over the nodes in the cluster (e.g. with a load balancer).

If you want to have more control over the distribution you can also use the `implicit` mode described [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud). Then the value within a field specified by you determines in which shard you enroll your document.

Comment: Hi. thx for answer. We have LB Haproxy, ip 10.10.10.10, Haproxy balancing between nodes. But when he choose 'sh2' or else node, he start insert all docs in one shard, maybe we can do distribution via solr scheme or configs? and we use `implict` mode

Comment: When you created your collection, what field did you choose for `router.field`? Which values are within this field?

Comment: i only enter `router.name=implicit`, `router.field` - nothing

`action=CREATE&name=coll1&numShards=2&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=2&router.name=implicit&collection.configName=coll1&shards=sh1,sh2,sh3`